# Do we need a tag [csv-file]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

I see we have a [csv-file](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csv-file) tag with nine questions mostly quite old and at a brief reading either off-topic as about software operation or not really about the file type. We do not seem to have any other tag for file types. If this is up-voted I will get rid of the tags and vote to close any which seem to me off-topic.

Comment: +1. There are some questions where it's the only tag. You will have to think what to replace it with. You might find [tag:project-management] useful.

Comment: @amoeba is right: to get rid of the tag, it needs to be removed from every thread. So we need something else for those threads where it is the only tag. We can close old, off topic threads, but in some cases consider flagging them to be 'locked', if they have any value (even while off topic).

Comment: @amoeba has made a good suggestion as I was unaware of that tag and it does look as though it would be suitable.

Comment: @gung I will do the easy ones first starting tomorrow and then if in doubt come back here.

Comment: It seems the tag is empty.

Comment: @amoeba Last time I looked there were still three there so someone must have lent a helping hand. I think the appropriate thing is for me to post an answer and accept it.

Comment: I did the last two yesterday. Don't know about the third.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag has now been emptied so this thread can be closed. I will accept my own answer.